# High latency in loading the document file for nodes using Twitter embeds

Tags: performance, drupal, twitter, drupal-7, latency

I am having the issue that nodes on my Drupal 7 blog (...) load very slowly. The issue is caused by a high latency in retrieving the document file. The Drupal blog exhibits a disproportionately high latency in general (compared to non-drupal pages on the domain), however nodes with Twitter embeds (...) exhibit extreme latencies of >20s in retrieving the document.

Since I am on a shared hosting with no SSH access, I cannot install APC. Development modules are switched off. Disabling the installed Twitter module does not help. The script after each Twitter blockquote is as follows:

The issue is not related to the custom sub theme, deactivating the sub theme does not improve the performance (latency). The latency occurs with every page-reload, caching does not improve the latency.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like retrieving the tweet threads takes a long time. Why don't you try retrieving the tweets client-side ?  So you relieve the server from doing that in every request to those pages.

Comment: Indeed, tweets should and are fetched client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue: it was stemming from the module "Link Title", disabling the module resolved the issue with the present configuration.